# element.scrollLeft like behavior inside of scrollable container without javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

### Question:

is there a way to simulate element.scrollLeft without javascript in order to pre-scroll a scrollable container?

### Background Context:

I have a scrollable container with items. Sometimes I have instances of this scrollable container that overflow & I would like the scroll offset to be at the end.

[image]

### Challenge

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by using javascript, but there is a noticeable jump or jank that is visible inside the scrollable container. **Is there a way to prescroll the container with just CSS?**

Code Sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9b9wt5?file=index.html

```js
const cardContainerEls = document.querySelectorAll('.card-container');
  cardContainerEls.forEach((el) => {
  el.scrollLeft = 1000;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with this fiddle which scrolls horizontally and vertically in pure CSS with no JavaScript. Maybe you can modify it for your needs:
https://jsfiddle.net/1Lfybv56/2/

HTML

```
<span id="top"></span>

<div id="anchors">
  <a href="#red">Red</a>
  <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
  <a href="#green">Green</a>
  <a href="#yellow">Yellow</a>
</div>

<div id="red"><a href="#top">Top</a></div>
<div id="blue"><a href="#top">Top</a></div>
<div id="green"><a href="#top">Top</a></div>
<div id="yellow"><a href="#top">Top</a></div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#anchors a {
  display: block;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
}

div {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

#red {
    background: red;
    left: calc(412px * 1);
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
    left: calc(412px * 2);
}
#green {
    background: green;
    left: calc(412px * 3);
}
#yellow {
    background: yellow;
    left: calc(412px * 4);
}
```